# MiniDP to VGA/HDMI or HDMI to HDMI

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have external monitor with VGA and HDMI ports, i plan to connect my macbook pro (mid 2014) to connect it.

What's the best way of doing this: Direct HDMI to HDMI connection, or MiniDP to HDMI/VGA adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use the built-in HDMI port, but if for some reason you need to use the MiniDP, it's a better idea to use a MiniDP to HDMI cable instead of a MiniDP to VGA cable since VGA is analog, which means it's lower quality video and it has no audio.

Comment: So if ext monitor has the minidisplay or displayport, then better is miniDP?

Comment: I don't think there's a lot of difference between HDMI and DisplayPort, but you can use that too.